# Problems with Install of Cartopy on Python3 MacOS

Tags: python-3.x, macos, cartopy

I have installed the latest versions of Proj and GEOS but still get the following error when Installing Cartopy. Proj and Geos installed fine and I double checked their install.

pip install Cartopy
Collecting Cartopy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e5/92/fe8838fa8158931906dfc4f16c5c1436b3dd2daf83592645b179581403ad/Cartopy-0.17.0.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /var/folders/hn/gs9rm9416l72qbz4bsqd0w5r0000gn/T/tmp9zqrg2u1:
  ERROR: setup.py:171: UserWarning: Unable to determine GEOS version. Ensure you have 3.3.3 or later installed, or installation may fail.
    '.'.join(str(v) for v in GEOS_MIN_VERSION), ))
  setup.py:227: UserWarning: Unable to determine Proj version. Ensure you have 4.9.0 or later installed, or installation may fail.
    '.'.join(str(v) for v in PROJ_MIN_VERSION), ))
  Proj version 0.0.0 is installed, but cartopy requires at least version 4.9.0.

---

ERROR: Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /var/folders/hn/gs9rm9416l72qbz4bsqd0w5r0000gn/T/tmp9zqrg2u1" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/hn/gs9rm9416l72qbz4bsqd0w5r0000gn/T/pip-install-yh57wjuy/Cartopy

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and fixed it on my machine by installing using conda instead of pip, which is what the project reccomends https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/installing.html